# Does the current progress towards the next skill level carry over when training?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, you can level up your skilly 'manually' or by training. Each training session raises the level of the respective skill by 1. I'm wondering if this just raises my current skill level to the next full level with zero progression to the next level or if my current progress towards the next level carries over when training.

For example, let's say I have speech level 89 with the progress bar towards level 90 half full. I then use the master trainer to level up to level 90. I'm now level 90, but will my progress bar towards level 91 be completely empty or half full?

**Side note:** Same question, but for skill books?

Comment: I want to say that it would keep your progress, but honestly, it's never something I had paid attention to... I'll make sure to track it on my next session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried it out (saved right before training as a safety measure) and it seems the progress does indeed carry over. I was at Speach level 88 with the progress bar towards 89 almost filled. I trained two times with Giraud Gemane (the maximum amount possible, as even the master trainer can't train you past level 90), now I am level 90 with the progress bar towards level 91 almost filled.

The same applies to books, I've tried it out as well.

Comment: might want to mark this down as the answer

Comment: @KevinFischer I thought I had, thanks for the reminder

Comment: Not a problem! Glad i could help